# How to change the relationship field in Pyrostreams entry form

Tags: pyrocms

I'm using Pyrostreams and I have 2 streams:

Cities &
Rooms

Rooms have a relationship field: City. When I output an entry form for Rooms I see a dropdown with all cities, but only their id's are shown. How can I show a specific field in the dropdowns of relationships (such as city_name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Adam Fairholm on the forum of PyroCMS:

> You need to set the title column of the stream by going into the field
>   you want to show and choosing Make Field the Title Column. This only
>   works for fields that have text to display, obviously, since it needs
>   to be shown in a drop down.